# Create a list of objects without an array

Tags: javascript

I need to get data in this format:

```
{
    name: 'template',
    type: index
},
{
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
},
setTemplateList(), 
{
    name: 'template',
    type: index
},…
```

They should not be in an array, because I return them as is to another file containing objects.

Here’s what I’m trying to do:

```
export function setTemplateList() {
      const templateList = [
  {title: 'About', value: 'aboutTemplate'},
  {title: 'Contact', value: 'contactTemplate'}
]
    
      let object = {};
    
      templateList.forEach(function (index, value) {
        let obj = {
          name: 'template',
          type: value.value
        }
    
        // I want to push into object here
      });
    
      return object;
    }
```

How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: can JSON Array help you?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  The format you describe looks like an array, just without the enclosing square brackets.  (And with a function call as an element for some reason?)  And in the next code snippet, what you describe is exactly an array (looping over another array and pushing elements onto a new array).  Can you clarify the exact resulting data structure you need, what you've attempted to build that structure, and what isn't working as expected?  Perhaps with a runnable [mcve] as a code snippet to demonstrate?

Comment: Thank you. @David i try to return a list of json object, but not in an array. My example is not good because I can’t do it. setTemplateList() must return JSON objects but not to an array

Comment: it's not perfectly clear to me why you need your output data to be something different than an array. If that wasn't a violation, to push the newly created object inside a previously initialized array, would be as easy as `templates.push(object)`. But you clearly forbidden that option. Maybe did you mean to use a custom data structure like a linked list?

Comment: as an example, it could simply be object[newIndexKey] = newObj

Comment: In your example, you are separating objects by commas, that refers to a collection and it must be wrapped to group them.

Maybe you can create an array and then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expand it.

Comment: @Jeremy JSON objects exist only in the mind of people that didn't get the point.. still you didn't clear out the point how you expect to compose the collection of objects if not using an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds to me* like what you're trying to do is inject elements into an array without those elements *themselves* being an array.  So, for example, imagine this array structure:

```
[
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  }
]
```

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to be able to invoke a function in the middle of this structure:

```
[
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  },
  someFunction()
]
```

And that function should return more then one element to be added to this overall array, resulting in:

```
[
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  }
]
```

But you *don't* want that function to return *an array*, because that would result in:

```
[
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  },
  [
    {
      name: 'template',
      type: index
    },
    {
      name: 'template',
      type: index 
    }
  ]
]
```

Which, while structureally permitted in JavaScript, is not the structure you want.

In this case, it sounds like you already have what you want but just need to change how you use it.

The function *should* return an array.  In fact, it has to.  Because that's how a group of objects is structured... as an array.  *However*, you don't have to embed the array itself into your structure.  You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the result of the function into the overall array:

```
[
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index
  },
  {
    name: 'template',
    type: index 
  },
  ...someFunction() // <-- note the spread operator here
]
```

What this would do is take the result of the function (an array) and add its *contents* to the overall structure, rather than add the result itself to the overall structure.  Which would result in one overall consistent array structure.

Comment: Wow! Perfect answer. I learned something today! Thank you for trying to understand and help me, I appreciate it! That’s exactly what I needed. You explain much better than me!